# Bash: [ -f ] && echo 1 # What is the file that checked correctly?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

What file is checked as existed and regular one when I do not add any file name in expression: `[ -f ] && echo 1`?

```
$ [ -f ] &&  echo "1"
1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No file is checked. `[` interprets its arguments based on the *number* of arguments it receives (ignoring `]`).

In this case, with only *one* argument, `-f` is not a unary operator; it is simply a non-empty string. That means it is equivalent to `[ -n -f ]`, which succeeds because the argument to the unary operator `-n` is indeed not empty.

Comment: I rolled back an edit that put `-f` in quotes because the quotes don't actually change the meaning, and actually *obscure* the point that how `-f` is interpreted is entirely dependent on context.